# OneToOneFields; post requests all return 400 now

Tags: django

I have:

```
class Thing(BaseModel):
    #doesn't matter

class OtherThing(BaseModel):
    thing = models.OneToOneField( Thing,
    related_name = 'other_thing',
    null         = True,
    blank        = True,
)
```

Now my django backend wont allow me to persist a thing model while other_thing is set to null in the payload. Which doesn't make any sense to me conceptually, if I can never save the first part of a 1-2-1, how could I ever save the second?

To be more specific, post requests to api/things return 400; {"other_thing": ["This field may not be null."]}

Serializers:

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model  = Thing
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'other_thing')

class OtherThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model  = OtherThing
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'thing')
```

Comment: Are you using an API framework? What does your API code look like? Not enough information.

Comment: There isn't really anything to it, it just makes it call full_clean on saves, gives it a __str__ method, stuff like that. It was working when it was a ForeignKey, and stopped working when it was converted to a OneToOneField, so the question is if there is anything intrinsic to 1-2-1 that I'm missing.

Comment: show your serializers

Comment: Something, somewhere returns the 400 error. Either it is your own code or it is a framework. If it is your code, you need to post it. If it is a framework, you need at least tell us which one is it. Is it DRF? Is it Tastypie? Is it something else?

Comment: Oh, it's definitely DRF, I'm sorry, I didn't mean to make my question so cryptic, I honestly just ran out of ideas. And it's definitely not my code returning the error.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, I needed to set 'other_thing' as a read_only_field like so;

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model  = Thing
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'other_thing')
    read_only_field = ('other_thing',)
```

This keeps Django from expecting it in the payload when POSTs come in, but will still send it over when a Thing is requested.